# To find the singular point of $y=\frac{2x^2-8}{x^2-16}$

Tags: calculus

It's given in my text book that the tangent at the origin can found out by equating to zero the lowest degree terms in $x$ and $y$. Therefore, by manipulating-

$yx^2-16y-2x^2+8=0$, the lowest degrees terms are $-16y-2x^2$, therefore-
$x=\pm \sqrt{-8y}$, which is imaginary. Thus, we have a conjugate.

But the graph of  $y=\frac{2x^2-8}{x^2-16}$ doesn't prove the findings.

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: The lowest degree term is $-16y$

Comment: By "tangent at the origin" I assume you mean the derivative of y at (0,0)?  If so, the point (0,0) is not on the curve so there is no tangent at the origin, that may explain it.

Comment: $x=\pm\sqrt{-8y}$ is only imaginary if $y > 0$.

Comment: When you say "singular point", do you mean you're trying to find the singularities? If so, there are two, corresponding to when $x^2 - 16 = 0$.

Comment: That curve does not pass through the origin in $xy$-rectangular coordinates.

Answer (score 1):

**HINT**: The singular points are the values of $x$ for which $y$ diverges. Look at the conditions when the denominator of the expression for $y$ equates to $0$, and when $x \to \pm\infty$.